# How to create a function for finding the largest of 2 polygons by area in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, geometry, function

I tried my level in creating the function but it shows error while running.

I have enclosed the code here :

```
create function largest_poly (geom1, geom2)
returns geometry as $largest_poly$
begin
from plpygis import Geometry
ST_Area(geom1 ST_Polygon),
ST_Area(geom2 ST_Polygon)
 poly largest_poly=Null
for
 (poly ST_Area: geom){
 {If (largest_poly==Null)|| ST_Area.geom() > largest_poly.ST_Area())
    largest_poly=ST_Area
 }
 return largest_poly;
}
end;
$largest_poly$ language plpygis;
```

Comment: Why a function, when it can be done with straight SQL

Comment: yes, Mr. J. Monticolo gave the answer and it was working perfectly with sql language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the examples in the `plpygis` [documentation](https://plpygis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html), it gives :

> Some functions that analyze or manipulate geometries are possible in
>   SQL but are easier to model in a procedural language. The following
>   example will use Shapely to find the largest component polygon of a
>   multipolygon.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION largest_poly(geom geometry)
  RETURNS geometry
AS $$
  from plpygis import Geometry
  polygons = Geometry(geom)
  if polygons.type == 'Polygon':
      return polygons
  elif polygons.type == 'MultiPolygon':
      largest = max(polygons.shapely, key=lambda polygon: polygon.area)
      return Geometry.from_shapely(largest)
  else:
      return None
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

> A pure PL/pgSQL function will have significantly better performance:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION largest_poly_fast(polygons geometry)
  RETURNS geometry
AS $$
  WITH geoms AS (
      SELECT (ST_Dump(polygons)).geom AS geom
  )
  SELECT geom
  FROM geoms
  ORDER BY ST_Area(geom) DESC LIMIT 1;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

From the second code, we can modify it a little bit :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION largest_poly(geom1 geometry, geom2 geometry)
  RETURNS geometry
AS $$
  WITH geoms AS (
      SELECT geom1 AS geom
      UNION ALL SELECT geom2
  )
  SELECT geom
  FROM geoms
  ORDER BY ST_Area(geom) DESC LIMIT 1;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. Then there is no use of case statement in finding this answer?

Comment: There's no reason to put a Python function in your answer. It looks like you're recommending using it.

Comment: In the question, the given code call a python module and I paste the Python documentation example for show that is not mandatory and less powerful to use Python here. But, the code gives the Python working syntax. I just don't know if using Python in the question was a choice or a lack of solutions.

Comment: I just want the solution from plpgsql which was given by you. I am wondering that how the subquery gives the answer and it seems to be correct. But while querying what will the solution for the first and second codes whether I need to give name of the polygon or Id. May I have an example. This is my example of querying                     " select largest_poly(geo_gem_01, geo_gem_05);"  where geo_gem_01 and geo_gem_05 are polygons.

Comment: while running the second code using postgresql it gives some mistake and if we refer geom1 as geom in 5th line then the geom in the 8th line will be geom1 and the answer automatically geom1 so there should be some changes

Comment: The first two are from the documentation. Only the last one is answering your question.

Comment: Yes, I am mentioned about the last one. There should be some change need to be done. Because I didn't get any answer from that. Do you know that? or you got any answer for that?  I can also send you the query but didn't worked.  SELECT largest_polygon1(geom1,geom2) FROM
(SELECT geom AS geom1, geom AS geom2 FROM geo_gem_01 LIMIT 1) AS a;

Comment: It's working here even if in your case `geom1` equals `geom2`. The only modifications I made are the name of the function `largest_poly` as in my post, and the name of the table.

Comment: May I know how you queried and got the answer?

Comment: `SELECT largest_poly(geom1,geom2) FROM (SELECT geom AS geom1, geom AS geom2 FROM public.my_table LIMIT 1) AS a;`

Comment: that's comparing the same geometry  @Karthik what's your use case?

Comment: I got the solution on friday and it also worked for me. Now I am learning to use 'case' statement to get this answer .

Comment: You can update your original post and submit your progression. If you found the best solution for you, post it as an answer.

Comment: where can I update my original post with correct answer that is the same you did, whether here in the comments or separately as I am new in using this I am not much aware.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour, `Improve posts by editing or commenting` section.

Comment: I have given the green tick to the answer it was the one I did.